# Cisco CSR user-data bootstrap to allow multiline in banner

Tags: amazon-web-services, cisco, user-data, cisco-ios, ec2-userdata

The user data format for the IOS appliance uses the following:

```
ios-config-0001="hostname test-csr-deployment-001"
ios-config-0002="banner exec |Hostname: test-csr-deployment-001\r\nRegion: eu-west-2|"
```

The commands are accepted, but the returned value is not split to multiline

```
show banner exec
Hostname: test-csr-deployment-001rnRegion: eu-west-2
```

How do I split the multiline?

I've also tried:

```
ios-config-0002="banner exec |Hostname: test-csr-deployment-001\015\012Region: eu-west-2|"
output:
Hostname: test-csr-deployment-001015012Region: eu-west-2

ios-config-000x="set NEWL &quot;\0&quot;"
ios-config-000x="set NEWL1 &quot;12&quot;"
ios-config-000x="set NEWL $NEWL$NEWL1"
ios-config-000x="banner exec |Hostname: test-csr-deployment-001$NEWLRegion: eu-west-2|"
error:
Invalid input detected at '^' marker
output:
Hostname: test-csr-deployment-001$NEWLRegion: eu-west-2

ios-config-0002="banner exec |Hostname: test-csr-deployment-001"
ios-config-0003="Region: eu-west-2|"
error:
Invalid input detected at '^' marker
output:
Hostname: test-csr-deployment-001
```

I also tried double escapes, but the config then doesn't load at all.

Ideally output should be:

```
show banner exec
Hostname: test-csr-deployment-001
Region: eu-west-2
```

Answer (score 0):

While configuring via CLI, we use the delimiter marks the beginning and the end of the message and new lines are accepted as far they are within the delimiter.

I don't know what language you are using in typical python way we could do something like this

```py
ios-config-0002='''banner exec # Line 1
Line 2 # '''
```